# Upload a file in s3 to another server using aws lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-lambda, multipartform-data

I want to read a file from s3 and upload it as a multipart object to another server using an aws lambda(java). What is the best possible way to do this?

Comment: are you sending this file from the browser?

Comment: thank you for reply. I did it